# $PS1 vs $PROMPT_COMMAND in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, prompt

I'd like to customize my shell's prompt. What are the differences between `$PS1` and `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, and what variable should I use? Some historic conventions (of past shells/posix) to find out what is more compatible would be nice to know.

Answer (score 6):

`PROMPT_COMMAND` is used to introduce annoying delays by executing one or more commands before each prompt is printed to the terminal.

`PS1` is used to set the primary terminal prompt.  It is useful when kept within the bounds of good taste and moderation (e.g. `PS1='\h:\w\$ '`) but is often abused to add annoyances like pointless bling (garish colours, beeping, blinking, etc), wasting valuable vertical screen space (multi-line prompts) and messing up the terminal with improperly-terminated ESC sequences.  Via command substitution, it can also add even more annoying delays by executing commands as each prompt is printed.

For more details, run `man bash` and search for `^PROMPTING`.  There are also descriptions for various prompt-related variables (`PS0`..`PS4`, `PROMPT_COMMAND`, `PROMPT_DIRTRIM`) in the `Shell Variables` sub-section of the man page.

Comment: Ok, I laughed at this